# Fluentd agent setup on GCP VM is not pushing logs to Logs Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, fluentd, google-cloud-logging

We have setup a fluentd agent on a GCP VM to push logs from syslog server (the VM) to GCP's Google Cloud Logging. The current setup is working fine and is pushing more than 300k log entries to Stackdriver (Google Cloud Logging) per hour.

Due to increased traffic, we are planning to increase the number of VMs employed behind the load balancer. However, the new VM with fluentd agent is not being able to push logs to Stackdriver. After the first time activation of VM, it does send a few entries to Stackdriver and after that, it does not work.

I tried below options to setup the fluentd agent and to resolve the issue:

1. Create a new VM from scratch and install fluentd logging agent using this [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/installation).
2. Duplicate the already working VM (with logging agent) by creating [Images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images)
3. Restart the VM
4. Reinstall the logging agent

Debugging I did:

1. All the configurations for google fluentd agent. Everything is correct and is also exactly similar to the currently working VM instance.
2. I checked the "/var/log/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.log" for any logging errors. But there are none.
3. Checked if the logging API is enabled. As there are already a few million logs per day, I assume we are fine on that front.
4. Checked the CPU and memory consumption. It is close to 0.
5. All the solutions I could find on Google (there are not many)

It would be great if someone can help me identify where exactly I am going wrong. I have checked configurations/setup files multiple times and they look fine.

Comment: can you check if your new VM has same permissions/VPC/firewall as the old VM which was working

Comment: Try doing ssh into the VM and restart fluentd by using **sudo /etc/init.d/google-fluentd restart**, also restart the google fluentd service by **sudo service google-fluentd restart** and check if the logs were being published.

Comment: Yes, the new VM has the same firewall permissions as the old one.
And I did try restarting the service. Didn't work.

Comment: Did you try restarting fluentd by using **sudo /etc/init.d/google-fluentd restart** command?

Comment: Yes, I did. Logging is still now working.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you confirm whether you are able to see logs now or not?

Comment: I am not able to see the logs.

Comment: 1. Are you using the latest version of the agent, if not try upgrading the agent. 2. Also make sure if you are running very old Compute Engine instances or Compute Engine instances created without the default credentials you must complete the [Authorizing the agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/authorization) procedures as per [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/installation#aws_connector_project). 3. If you are using an HTTP proxy for proxying requests to the Logging and Monitoring APIs, check whether the metadata server is reachable.

Comment: 4. Can you see logs being produced on any of the locations,but not appearing as logs in log explorer? 5. Also try uninstalling the Fluentd
agent and try to use [Ops agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent) instead (note that syslog logs are collected by it with no setup) and check whether you were able to see the logs.

Answer (score 0):

**Troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue:**

1. Check whether you are using the latest version of the fluentd agent or not. If not, try upgrading the fluentd agent. Refer to [upgrade the agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/installation#upgrade) for information.
2. If you are running very old Compute Engine instances or Compute Engine instances created without the default credentials you must complete the [Authorizing the agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/logging/authorization) procedures.
3. Another point to focus is, how you are Configuring an HTTP Proxy. If you are using an HTTP proxy for proxying requests to the Logging and Monitoring APIs, check whether the metadata server is reachable.  The metadata server has to be reachable (and do it directly; no proxy) when Configuring an HTTP Proxy.
4. Check if you have any log exclusions configured which is preventing the logs from arriving. Refer [Exclusion filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/overview#exclusions) for information.
5. Try uninstalling the Fluentd agent and try to use Ops agent instead (note that syslog logs are collected by it with no setup) and check whether you were able to see the logs. Combining logging and metrics into a single agent, the Ops Agent uses Fluent Bit for logs, which supports high-throughput logging, and the [OpenTelemetry Collector](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/collector/) for metrics. Refer [Ops agent](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/agents/ops-agent) for more information.